# Tabela pdf utilizando EZPDF em PHP

Tags: php, pdf, tabela-html, relatório

Estou tentando gerar uma tabela em pdf com ezpdf na linguagem PHP em um projeto antigo. O código que consegui fazer foi:

```
<?php

include("banco/banco.php");

include("./ezpdf/class.ezpdf.php");

error_reporting(0);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos ORDER BY nomeProduto ASC";
$resultado = $banco->query($sql);
$qtd = $resultado->num_rows;

if ($qtd > 0) {
    $conteudo_pdf = array();
    $conteudo_pdf[] = array("Codigo", "Produto");
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $conteudo_pdf[] = array(
            "Codigo" => $row["cod_produto"],
            "Produto" => $row["nomeProduto"]
        );
    }
    $pdf = new Cezpdf();
    $pdf->selectFont('./fonts/Helvetica.afm');
    $pdf->ezTable($conteudo_pdf);
    $pdf->ezStream();
} else {
    echo "Nenhum resultado encontrado.";
}
?>
```

Contudo, é apresentando no pdf a quantidade de linhas existentes no banco de dados, mas não é exibido as informações.

Se tiver alguem que possa ajudar.

Comment: [Essa pergunta já havia sido postada agora há pouco](/q/589572). Importante seguir as orientações dadas na postagem original. Para evitar descentralização de informações, o campo de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas você pode utilizar o da postagem original, restaurando-a.